# Access images used in browser themes?

Tags: image, http, browser, themes

Is it possible for a website to call images that are used in browser themes or plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a security bug.

Only way to do this would be by knowing the path to user's firefox profile dir. You could link to those files with  and use onload to find out if they exist.

But You would have to get user to give You the path and You'd probably ewncounter cross-domain issues.

Comment: ...and you'll have to convince the user to actually use Firefox... :-)

Comment: Yup, that's right. But I'm not even sure if IE has themes as I'm using Linux.

Comment: Chrome has themes. IE uses the OS theme. Couple of browsers on top of Trident (IE engine) have themes.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no standard way of doing this.